# How to use addAction button to cancel the ongoing service

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to make Screen dimmer app for which will be just have on/off function and that too from notification.
How to implement cancel service of pendingintent by using .addAction?

I can stop the service by stopSelf() from Service.class, and not from MainActivity but how to implement that in the notification ?

```
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.class), 0);

    final Notification notification = new
            NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setTicker("Transparent Lock")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_blur_on_black_24dp)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            //.addAction(R.drawable.ic_blur_on_black_24dp, "Cancel", ????? )
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_SECRET)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();

    final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: you could implement a listener which can talk to your service to perform the stopping.

Comment: i tried but it gives an error when i use stopService()/stopself  as it is not pending intent

Answer (score 0):

Working code is given below,

1) Function to create a notification,

Call this function to create a notification. title,body,context,notificationsId these are all parameters i'am passing as per my requirement, you can remove it if you don't want.

```
    public void createBigNotificationAcceptOrRejectAlert() {

        final int noId= new Random().nextInt(61) + 20;
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notifystyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        RemoteViews contentView =
          new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_big_notification);//using a custom layout
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Title");
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.desc, "Message");

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
          new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon( R.drawable.ic_blur_on_black_24dp)
            .setStyle(notifystyle)
            .setCustomBigContentView(contentView)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setTicker("Transparent Lock")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(body);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
          (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
          mBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
        setListeners(contentView, String.valueOf(noId));// 

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent =
          PendingIntent.getActivity(this, noId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

        mNotificationManager.notify(noId, notification);
      }
```

2) Function to Listen for Button Click,

This is a function which is used to provide listeners for the button, this function is called from the above function.

```
public void setListeners(RemoteViews view, String noId) 

    Intent radio =
      new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationApproveOrReject.class);
    radio.putExtra("DO", "tvConfirm");
    radio.putExtra("noId", noId);

    PendingIntent pRadio = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), Integer.parseInt(noId), radio,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btAccept, pRadio);

    Intent volume =
      new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationApproveOrReject.class);
    volume.putExtra("DO", "tvCancel");
    volume.putExtra("noId", noId);

    PendingIntent pVolume = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), Integer.parseInt(noId), volume,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btReject, pVolume);
  }
```

3) Class to handle the click,

Finally, create a new class to handle the click action.Don't forget to add this class in manifest.

```
public class NotificationApproveOrReject extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Reached", "Section1");
    String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("DO");
    final String id = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("noId");

    Log.d("RandomNumberReached", id);

    if (action.equals("tvConfirm")) {
     //Your action
    } else if (action.equals("tvCancel")) {

 //Your action
  }
}
  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```

4) Layout that i used layout_big_notification,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/title"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen10"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen10"
          android:textColor="#ccc"
          android:textSize="@dimen/textSize14"
          tools:text="Test"
          />
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/desc"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen10"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen1"
          android:textColor="#ccc"
          android:textSize="@dimen/textSize12"
          tools:text="Test"
          />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:gravity="end"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btAccept"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen5"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen10"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen10"
        android:text="@string/accept"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize14"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btReject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen5"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen10"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen10"
        android:text="@string/reject"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize14"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen10"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:contentDescription="@null"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

hope, it may help you.

Comment: bhai thanks for the code, but I don't understand anything, I am a beginner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165402/discussion-between-sachin-varma-and-ravi-kilnake).